# Change spiderman tag to spider-man?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I know this may seem pretty nitpicky, but can we change the [spiderman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spiderman) tag to [spider-man](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-man)?  That's the correct spelling of his name (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-man) for a quick example).

Comment: Just for the record, that hyphen always bugged me (pun intended). Do we know why it is hyphenated, and Bat-man isn't? Is is a Marvel/DC thing? Should I make this a question? :)

Comment: @Nobby SciFi have that question  [Why are “Batman” and “Superman” both one word but “Spider-Man” is hyphenated?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19958/why-are-batman-and-superman-both-one-word-but-spider-man-is-hyphenated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCD much?

Done :P